# Apply Order of Spring Aspects with Same Order

Tags: spring, aspect

Suppose multiple aspects are in application and be applied on a certain method. The annotation `@order` or `Ordered` interface can specify their precedence.

But if the values of `@Order` **are same**, how to determine the apply order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **When two pieces of advice defined in different aspects both need to run at the same join point, unless you specify otherwise the order of execution is undefined**. You can control the order of execution by specifying precedence. This is done in the normal Spring way by either implementing the org.springframework.core.Ordered interface in the aspect class or annotating it with the Order annotation. Given two aspects, the aspect returning the lower value from Ordered.getValue() (or the annotation value) has the higher precedence.

It cannot be controlled, reference from doc [6.2.4.7](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html)